# mongoose findById не работает

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Прошу сильно не пинать.
Изучаю nodejs, express и mongodb
Попутно пытаюсь сделать все что показано в этом [скринкасте](https://youtu.be/YZwAVRsa1O4?list=PLDyvV36pndZFWfEQpNixIHVvp191Hb3Gg&t=116)
Но в этом месте:

```
    app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res, next){
  User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, user){
    if(err) return next(err);
    res.json(user);
  });
});
```

Вываливается ошибка:

```
 Express
500 CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "586f2862632df73c31f25df3" at path "_id" for model "User"
   at MongooseError.CastError (/home/farex/dev/nodejs_dev/lessons_30/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/cast.js:26:11)
   at ObjectId.cast (/home/farex/dev/nodejs_dev/lessons_30/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectid.js:147:13)
   at ObjectId.castForQuery (/home/farex/dev/nodejs_dev/lessons_30/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectid.js:187:15)
   at cast (/home/farex/dev/nodejs_dev/lessons_30/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast.js:229:32)
   at Query.cast (/home/farex/dev/nodejs_dev/lessons_30/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2752:12)
   at Query.findOne (/home/farex/dev/nodejs_dev/lessons_30/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1353:10)
   at Function.findOne (/home/farex/dev/nodejs_dev/lessons_30/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:1343:13)
   at Function.findById (/home/farex/dev/nodejs_dev/lessons_30/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:1271:15)
   at /home/farex/dev/nodejs_dev/lessons_30/app.js:42:8
   at callbacks (/home/farex/dev/nodejs_dev/lessons_30/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
   at param (/home/farex/dev/nodejs_dev/lessons_30/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
   at param (/home/farex/dev/nodejs_dev/lessons_30/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:135:11)
   at pass (/home/farex/dev/nodejs_dev/lessons_30/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)
   at Router._dispatch (/home/farex/dev/nodejs_dev/lessons_30/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:173:5)
   at Object.router (/home/farex/dev/nodejs_dev/lessons_30/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
   at next (/home/farex/dev/nodejs_dev/lessons_30/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:174:15)
```

Похоже в новой версии mobgoose, что-то поменялось...

Answer (score 0):

Тему можно считать закрытой,
Собственно помогло:

mongodb 3 версия.

mongoose 2 версия.

как у автора скринкаста.

Comment: не забудьте принять свой собственный ответ